# Square of list in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

I am making function in Haskell to get the square of the list. Here is my code

```
sqrall :: [Int] -> [Int]
sqrall [] = []
sqrall [x] =  map (^2) x
```

But that code is not working.i don't know where i am missing.. Please help me..

Comment: Note that the empty list base case is unnecessary here, as `map` handles empty lists just fine, and in the way you are thinking of. Cf. pdoherty926's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to remove the square brackets from the non-empty list pattern on the left side of your function definition.

The following will work:

```
sqrall x = map (^2) x
sqrall [1,2,3] -- [1,4,9]
```

Comment: Which we can eta-reduce to `sqrall = map (^2)`